How can I return the chunks that are being used in the query?
import { ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/openai";
import { formatDocumentsAsString } from "langchain/util/document";
import { PromptTemplate } from "@langchain/core/prompts";
import {
  RunnableSequence,
  RunnablePassthrough,
} from "@langchain/core/runnables";
import { StringOutputParser } from "@langchain/core/output_parsers";

import { PineconeStore } from "@langchain/pinecone";

import { Pinecone } from '@pinecone-database/pinecone';


export default async function langchain() {

  const model = new ChatOpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    temperature: 0,
    streaming: true,
  });


  async function getVectorStore() {
    try {
      const client = new Pinecone({
        apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINECONE_API_KEY || 'mal'
      });

      const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
        apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY,
        batchSize: 1536,
        model: "text-embedding-ada-002",
      });

      const index = client.Index(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINECONE_INDEX_NAME || 'mal');

      const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(embeddings, {
        pineconeIndex: index,
        namespace: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT,
        textKey: 'text',
      });

      return vectorStore;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error ', error);
      throw new Error('Something went wrong while getting vector store!');
    }
  }

  const formatChatHistory = (chatHistory: [string, string][]) => {
    const formattedDialogueTurns = chatHistory.map(
      (dialogueTurn) => `Human: ${dialogueTurn[0]}\nAssistant: ${dialogueTurn[1]}`
    );
    return formattedDialogueTurns.join("\n");
  };

  const condenseQuestionTemplate = `Given the following conversation and a follow-up question, rephrase the follow-up question to be a standalone question, in its original language.

  Chat History:
  {chat_history}
  Follow Up Input: {question}
  Standalone question:`;
  const CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(
    condenseQuestionTemplate
  );

  const answerTemplate = `Answer the question based only on the following context:
  {context}

  Question: {question}
  `;
  const ANSWER_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(answerTemplate);

  type ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput = {
    question: string;
    chat_history: [string, string][];
  };

  const standaloneQuestionChain = RunnableSequence.from([
    {
      question: (input: ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput) => input.question,
      chat_history: (input: ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput) =>
        formatChatHistory(input.chat_history),
    },
    CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,
    model,
    new StringOutputParser(),
  ]);

  const vectorStore = await getVectorStore();
  const retriever = vectorStore.asRetriever( );

  const answerChain = RunnableSequence.from([
    {
      context: retriever.pipe(formatDocumentsAsString),
      question: new RunnablePassthrough(),
    },
    ANSWER_PROMPT,
    model,
  ]);

  const conversationalRetrievalQAChain =
    standaloneQuestionChain.pipe(answerChain );

  const result = await conversationalRetrievalQAChain.invoke({
    question: "Que es la SS?",
    chat_history: [],
  });

  console.log('Answer: ', result);

  return result;
}

I am making a simple RAG application using OpenAI, Pinecone as database and LangChain, it works and I get the expected response, but I can't find the way to return the chunks that were found as most similar, regularly in python in the retriver a parameter is specified as "return_source_documents=True" but I can't find the option in node.
System Info
I am using the versions:

langchain/community: 0.2.18
langchain/openai: 0.2.1
langchain/pinecone: 0.0.7
pinecone-database/pinecone: 2.2.2


In our case we solved this problem by using a method found inside the Store class we used. Our use case just required listing the most similar documents along the answer, so this served our needs.
In your case, PineconeStore has the similaritySearchVectorWithScore method which will return the most similar embeddings. You can find this documented here.

Yes, in my code, when I enter the question it searches in the most similar embeddings and it does it correctly and has no problems, when I pass it to the promp as "context" to the model, it also has no problems and the information is correct, my problem is that I need to know the metadata of those embeddings that I found most similar and save it in a varibale or something.

This is the solution to the problem, we do it by modifying this function:
  const answerChain = RunnableMap.from({
    context: retriever,
    question: new RunnablePassthrough(),
  }).assign({
    answer: RunnableSequence.from([
      (input: { context: Document[]; question: string }) => ({
        context: formatDocumentsAsString(input.context),
        question: input.question,
      }),
      ANSWER_PROMPT,
      model,
      new StringOutputParser(),
    ]),
  });

Complete code:
import { ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/openai";
import { formatDocumentsAsString } from "langchain/util/document";
import { PromptTemplate } from "@langchain/core/prompts";
import {
  RunnableSequence,
  RunnablePassthrough,
  RunnableMap,
} from "@langchain/core/runnables";
import { StringOutputParser } from "@langchain/core/output_parsers";
import { PineconeStore } from "@langchain/pinecone";
import { Pinecone } from '@pinecone-database/pinecone';

import { Document } from "langchain/document";

export default async function langchain() {

  const model = new ChatOpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    verbose: true,
    temperature: 0,
  });

  const condenseQuestionTemplate = `Given the following conversation and a follow up question, rephrase the follow up question to be a standalone question, in its original language.
  
  Chat History:
  {chat_history}
  Follow Up Input: {question}
  Standalone question:`;
  const CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(
    condenseQuestionTemplate
  );

  const answerTemplate = `Answer the question based only on the following context:
  {context}
  
  Question: {question}
  `;
  const ANSWER_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(answerTemplate);

  const formatChatHistory = (chatHistory: [string, string][]) => {
    const formattedDialogueTurns = chatHistory.map(
      (dialogueTurn) => `Human: ${dialogueTurn[0]}\nAssistant: ${dialogueTurn[1]}`
    );
    return formattedDialogueTurns.join("\n");
  };

  async function getVectorStore() {
    try {

      const client = new Pinecone({
        apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINECONE_API_KEY || 'mal'
      });

      const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
        apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY,
        batchSize: 1536,
        model: "text-embedding-3-small",
      });

      const index = client.Index(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINECONE_INDEX_NAME || 'mal');

      const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(embeddings, {
        pineconeIndex: index,
        namespace: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT,
        textKey: 'text',
      });

      return vectorStore;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error ', error);
      throw new Error('Something went wrong while getting vector store !');
    }
  }

  const vectorStore = await getVectorStore();

  const retriever = vectorStore.asRetriever();

  type ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput = {
    question: string;
    chat_history: [string, string][];
  };

  const standaloneQuestionChain = RunnableSequence.from([
    {
      question: (input: ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput) => input.question,
      chat_history: (input: ConversationalRetrievalQAChainInput) =>
        formatChatHistory(input.chat_history),
    },
    CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,
    model,
    new StringOutputParser(),
  ]);


  const answerChain = RunnableMap.from({
    context: retriever,
    question: new RunnablePassthrough(),
  }).assign({
    answer: RunnableSequence.from([
      (input: { context: Document[]; question: string }) => ({
        context: formatDocumentsAsString(input.context),
        question: input.question,
      }),
      ANSWER_PROMPT,
      model,
      new StringOutputParser(),
    ]),
  });

  const conversationalRetrievalQAChain = standaloneQuestionChain.pipe(answerChain);

  const result = await conversationalRetrievalQAChain.invoke({
    question: "De que se encargaron la SS?",
    chat_history: [],
  });

  console.log(result);

  return result;
}



As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
